# I got error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected

Tags: typescript, vue.js, compiler-errors

I got error when I deploy my website to vercel

> `src/views/home/Index.vue(453,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.`

but when i checked to line 453 it's showed `export default` and here's the full code from line 453

> ```
> export default{
> data() {
>     return {
>         form:{
>         nama: '',
>         telfon: '',
>         selected: '',
>         date: '',
>         message: '',
>         myDate: '',
>     }
> };
> },
> methods: {
>     whatsapp: function (e){
>         var nama = document.getElementById('nama').value;
>         var telfon = document.getElementById('telfon').value;
>         var servis = document.getElementById('servis').value;
>         var tanggal = document.getElementById('tanggal').value;
>         var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
>         var keluhan = document.getElementById('keluhan').value;
>
>         const whatsappurl = "https://wa.me/+6285156809429?text=Halo saya ingin booking service mobil%0a%0aNama Pelanggan: "+nama+"%0a"+
>             "Nomor Telfon Pelanggan: "+telfon+"%0a"+
>             "Jenis Servis: "+servis+"%0a"+
>             "Tanggal Servis: "+tanggal+"%0a"+
>             "Keluhan Kendaraan: "+keluhan+"%0a"+
>             "Request tambahan: "+message+"%0a";
>         
>         window.open(whatsappurl,'_blank').focus();
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

how I can solve this error ? Thank you

Comment: You could start with fixing your indentation, so you could see the mistakes if there are any. But the problem is likely that .vue is directly parsed by TS, which shouldn't be done because it's not valid JS/TS. This shouldn't happen and depends on your setup, which is unknown.